# Buying a certificate - what to spend and where

Tags: ssl-certificate

My boss wants to buy a certificate for his SBS so external connection can be made. they access on an IP number. What should he spend on the certificate? Where should he buy from?

Verisign seems like overkill as its not an ecommerce site, just needs some security. Ive seen some cheap ones at $20 / yr - are there any problems with getting cheap certificates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend GoDaddy for buying the certificates, good price.

As for linking to an ip address, I would not recommend that even if it's possible.  You want to link the certificate to your domain name, and point the domain or sub domain at your ip address in DNS.  This way if you change ISP's, you just update the new IP in the DNS and back in business, no need to adjust the Certificate.

Also for SBS make sure to watch closely which certificate.  I believe the multiple domain ones are recommended for SBS so that Exchange, Webmail, and Exchange over HTTP will all work.

Answer (score 1):

[StartCom](http://www.startssl.com/) provides free SSL certificates.
The StartCom Certification Authority is supported by the most common web browsers.

Comment: StartCom has been included in the Root Certificates Update for Internet Explorer since September 2009 (see Eddy Nigg's blog post "The 'e' of the Internet" dated August 19, 2009: http://blog.startcom.org/?p=205).

Comment: i just looked in my IE8 cert store and i am not seeing it.  also , the FAQ at StartCom suggests that with Firefox that you need to manually install the cert into the browser keystore.

Answer (score 0):

What does using a certificate have to do with "making external connections"?

Can you be more specific in what he wishes to do?

Comment: Sounds like he wants to use something like Outlook Web Access.  I suspect that it works with a self signed certificate, but it looks rather unprofessional to have users be warned that the certificate is self-signed.

Comment: That was my thought but see no reason it would be considered unprofessional for internal users.

Comment: I noticed that common users have no clue what a any of these words stand for "self-signed ssl certificate". They will maybe ask what to do if such a warning pops up.

Comment: Tell them "Click Accept the first time you check your e-mail."  Educating users how to behave is part of the job.  Bergin or his boss will have to teach them how to access it anyway; this adds 1 step 1 time.

Comment: If i had $10 for every user who asked me why they had to accept a warning, I'm sure I'd have enough for a SSL Certificate to save me having to answer those questions ever again.

Comment: 1 cert is fine but when you might have dozens for test/dev/internal-only use it might be worth the education.

Comment: @keith stokes:  "Tell the to click accept" is great if the software has a "Click to accept" option, not all do. Thunderbird for example does not.

Comment: @David,

Thunderbird 2.0.0.24 on my Windows machine has the option.

Comment: @keith, a domain cert is still only $200/yr, and not spending all that time "educating" users is worth $200 easily.

Comment: @Chris, go back up a couple of comments.  I agreed 1 cert @ $200/yar might be worth it but I have probably a dozen.  Does $1500/year make it more worth your or your boss's time?

It's never been a real problem at my place.

Comment: Teaching users to accept invalid SSL certificates is just asking for trouble.  If the connection is only ever being made from corporate-owned boxes then you can create your own certificate authority and get that trusted on all your machines, but just getting a cheap ssl certificate is the way to go here.

Comment: Well, Keith. sharepoint is running on a virtual server. you come in from the outside onto the broadband dedicated IP and the router port forwards to this internal server available as SSL. I think the boss was happy to have people pressing another button to avoid paying any fees. As Brian pointed out buying a cert for an IP number is a bad idea; should set up a domain name and point it to the broadband IP

Answer (score 0):

They shouldn't access on an IP address as you say, most Certificate Authorities won't certify that.

Comment: +1 and accessing via IP address is also asking for trouble when you have to change your IP address later on.  I know you're thinking you won't ever have to change the ip address, but you will.

Answer (score 0):

I use and recommend [GoDaddy](http://www.godaddy.com/ssl/ssl-certificates.aspx?ci=9039) (who actually resells Starfield Tech certs). The certs are $30/yr for a single computer, standard verification (blue bar on most browsers).

If you need something more complicated the prices goes up as they support more features. But the standard will work just fine; and is recognized by all modern browsers.

Answer (score 0):

You could try QuoVadis. They are generally a lot cheaper than people like Verisign. 
http://www.quovadisglobal.com/